# ListView OnItemClick Listener does not work?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to call the fragment from the fragment, on a list view `OnItemClick` Listener, but the click listener does not work for me.
I have setup the list items using the adapter.

Here is my code:

```
public class ProductListFragment extends Fragment {

    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    ListView listView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(new ProductListAdapter(getActivity()));

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new ProductFragment()).commit();

            }
        });

    return view;

     }
}
```

Comment: do you get a crash or it just do nothing ?

Comment: no its not getting crashed yer

Comment: Please debug on item click working or not?
And also please post the code of ProductFragment.Class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android listview onItemClickListener failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734290/android-listview-onitemclicklistener-failed)

Comment: public class ProductFragment extends Fragment {

 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_desc, null);
        return x;
    }
}

Comment: Post post whole code of current class.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code to replace fragment-

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new ProductFragment());
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**EDIT**

Please set view on Fragment class as -

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_desc,container,false);

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: No am not getting error, application runs but the fragment is not shown on clicking list

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing your `FragmentManager`.

```
public class ProductListFragment extends Fragment {

    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    ListView listView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(new ProductListAdapter(getActivity()));

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                /** initialize fragment manager */
                mFragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new ProductFragment()).commit();

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```